# Not enough permissions to access: GET-owners /shares - while fetching posts

Tags: api, permissions, request, linkedin-api

I am getting this error when trying to fetching posts from my linkedin account using linkedin api

I've checked that I'm using the correct API endpoint and have a valid access token. However, I'm still getting this error.

```
{
  "serviceErrorCode": 100,
  "message": "Not enough permissions to access: GET-owners /shares",
  "status": 403
}
```

I am using this api:
`https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares?q=owners&owners=urn:li:person:*********&scope=r_liteprofile%20r_emailaddress%20w_member_social`

#linkedin

I need a correct solution, and want to know the cause if this,
what I am missing in the request